# Where can I drive motorcycles in Europe with the Chinese driving license (C1)?

Tags: europe, driving-licenses, motorcycles, indonesian-citizens

I have a Schengen visa (the type is student, not travelling) and a Chinese driving license (C1).

I expect to take a motorcycle trip. My friend told me that they drove the motorcycle in 'Las Palmas de Gran Canaria' (Spain) only with the Chinese driving license (C1) without any additional documents like translation. It suprises me so much because a different type `E` (`C1` doesn't include `E`) is required to drive motocycle in China.

Are there other places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need a valid driver's license, translated to the language to where you will be traveling to (french, spanish, english...) and/or a valid international driver's license issued in China.

https://www.justlanded.com/english/France/Articles/Travel-Leisure/Driving-Licence

(edited)

Comment: Why French specifically?

Comment: Oups!! My Francophilia comes out!! Well, you should have it translated to where you plan to travel in Europe.

Comment: @C‘est quoi? [Francophile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francophile). `A Francophile (gallophile) is a person who has a strong affinity towards the French language, French history, French culture or french people.`

Answer (score 2):

To drive a motor cycle in Europe you need a motor cycle driving license, and an International Driving Permit, which is a translation of your Chinese license.

Your friend might have rented a moped or scooter, which is 50 cc maximum and does not require a motor license but which you can drive with any driving license as well as with a special '50 cc max' license. Those look like motor cycles or motor scooters but go no faster than 50 km/h by law.

Comment: I will double click it from my friend. Thx for ur reminder.

Comment: @SparkandShine it depends on the specific country you're visiting and how many cc/kW the motorcycle has.